# Connecting to Presto database using AWS Glue. Unable to pass SSL Keystore or Certificate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ssl, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have issue connecting to Presto using AWS glue job. The code is written in Spark Scala. I am trying to connect to Presto using the below code.

```
val datanot_in_hz = sqlcontext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", jdbcConUrl).option("driver", "io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriver").option("SSL","true").option("SSLKeyStorePath","s3://test/presto_client.keystore").option("query", datanot_in_hz_sql).option("user", dbUserName).option("password", dbPassword).load()
```

I get the below error

> 2020-12-18 20:36:52,376 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher
> (Logging.scala:logError(70)): Exception in User Class:
> java.sql.SQLException : Error setting up SSL:
> s3:/test/presto_client.keystore (No such file or
> directory)
> io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriverUri.setupClient(PrestoDriverUri.java:235)
> io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriver.connect(PrestoDriver.java:88)
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
> org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
> sddsurwithDAXreporting$.main(sddsurwithDAXreportingPresto.scala:89)
> sddsurwithDAXreporting.main(sddsurwithDAXreportingPresto.scala)
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.SparkProcessLauncherPlugin$class.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:38)
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$$anon$1.invoke(ProcessLauncher.scala:67)
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.launch(ProcessLauncher.scala:108)
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher$.main(ProcessLauncher.scala:21)
> com.amazonaws.services.glue.ProcessLauncher.main(ProcessLauncher.scala)

I tried passing pem certificate but still it fails with the same error. I have checked all the permission. I have a jar file which I access from the same folder, I am able to access that.
When I run the same code from my machine using Eclipse it runs fine. Can someone please help? I am fairly new to scala and this is my first attempt in using SSL certificate to connect to a database.

Comment: I think the s3 path is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS support recommended to copy file from S3 to tmp folder as during runtime as Glue was not able to read the path correctly